# Combine groups of jpg images into one jpg/png r

Tags: r, imagemagick, png, jpeg

I have a list of images that I would like to combine into one image per group. Each image has a name and what type of chart it is. I'm hoping there is a way to use the name to group the images and return an output of a single jpg or png for each group. the combined image would look like the following:

[image: combined]

The folder has a list of images with the following naming structure: In this case, I would like to have 3 output combined pngs based on bart, lisa and marge.

```
"bart Cum Oil.jpg"
"bart GOR.jpg"
"bart Legend.jpg"
"bart Oil Rate.jpg"
"lisa Cum Oil.jpg"
"lisa GOR.jpg"
"lisa Legend.jpg"
"lisa Oil Rate.jpg"
"marge Cum Oil.jpg"
"marge GOR.jpg"
"marge Legend.jpg"
"marge Oil Rate.jpg"
```

Below is a sample of four images that i would combine since all images have "bart" in the name.
[image: bart Cum Oil]
[image: bart GOR]
[image: bart Legend]
[image: bart Oil Rate]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `magick::image_montage`. The only trick is to create a 2x2 grid and insert a blank image as the 3rd object.

```r
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.12.3
#> Enabled features: cairo, freetype, fftw, ghostscript, heic, lcms, pango, raw, rsvg, webp
#> Disabled features: fontconfig, x11

imgs_url <- c('https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqnwC.png',
              'https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIDXh.png',
              'https://i.stack.imgur.com/B36ko.png')

imgs <- image_read(imgs_url)
imgs <- c(imgs[1:2], image_blank(width = 3, height = 5), imgs[3])

image_montage(imgs, tile = '2x2', geometry = "x200+3+5")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

If you want to group the images by name, one way is to capture the above workflow in a function, and add a `grepl` statement to identify which subset of images to plot.

I don't have all of the images, so this is untested. But it would look something like this.

```
my_files <- c("bart Cum Oil.jpg",
              "bart GOR.jpg",
              "bart Legend.jpg",
              "bart Oil Rate.jpg",
              "lisa Cum Oil.jpg",
              "lisa GOR.jpg",
              "lisa Legend.jpg",
              "lisa Oil Rate.jpg",
              "marge Cum Oil.jpg",
              "marge GOR.jpg",
              "marge Legend.jpg",
              "marge Oil Rate.jpg")

# remove oil rate image paths
my_files <- my_files[!grepl('Oil Rate', my_files)]


# create function 
make_grid <- function(group, path_to_files){
  
  f <- files[grepl(group, files)]
  
  imgs <- image_read(f)
  imgs <- c(imgs[1:2], image_blank(width = 3, height = 5), imgs[3])
  
  image_montage(imgs, tile = '2x2', geometry = "x200+3+5")

}


# create lisa image grid
make_grid('lisa', my_files)

# create all image grids
lapply(c('bart', 'lisa', 'marge'), make_grid, path_to_files = my_files)
```

Comment: Appreciate your help! This will work, however I'm getting stuck when i try to read in my files using file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.jpg')
my_files <- sapply(file.list, image_read, simplify=FALSE).. I get the following error, Error in image_read(f) : path must be URL, filename or raw vector

Comment: I'll go ahead and check yours as the answer as well.

Comment: What happens if you run `file.exists(file.list)`?

Comment: [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

Comment: got it working using files <- list.files(pattern="*.jpg", all.files=T, full.names=T)
filelist <- lapply(files, image_read)
names(filelist) <- paste0(basename((files)))
list2env(filelist, envir=.GlobalEnv)